# How to build a query for expected given result

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three table,

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d782f/4)

The problem is, its gives `null` values for another no available records in respect of all another rows

If its possible to merge data like,

```
id  qtype cyu
1   1     simple
2   2     op
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to take the non-null column values:

```
SELECT    qm.*, COALESCE(qs.cyu, qo.cyu)
FROM      qmaster qm
LEFT JOIN qsimple qs ON qm.id = qs.qm_id
LEFT JOIN qop qo ON qm.id = qo.qm_id
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d782f/7)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` to return the first non-NULL value:

```
coalesce( qs.cyu, qo.cyu )
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d782f/6)